# How is the operationId used from an OpenAPI schema?

Tags: openapi, swashbuckle

In an OpenAPI schema, it includes the optional element `operationId`.

How is this used and why is it optional? Well, at least with the .NET Core library "Swashbuckle" [they say it's optional](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#assign-explicit-operationids).

My guess is that it is linked to how an SDK is consumed. For example, I can make a Typescript SDK from any valid OpenAPI schema... so I'm guessing it's somehow linked to how that Typescript SDK is generated and then consumed/used?

Comment: There is a request to make the `OperationId` mandatory:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1907   ... I think this question might get a better audience right there

Answer (score 13):

The `operationId` section of the [Paths and Operators](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) page in the [OpenAPI Guide](https://swagger.io/docs/specification) describes this property as:

> `operationId` is an optional unique string used to identify an operation. If provided, these IDs must be unique among all operations described in your API.
>
> ...
>
> Some common use cases for `operationId` are:
>
> - Some code generators use this value to name the corresponding methods in code.
> - Links can refer to the linked operations by operationId.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, one of the primary uses for `operationId` is as a basis for the method name in a generated SDK.  But this is not the only use.  It might also be used, e.g., as an anchor in generated documentation. It could be used anywhere a unique identifier for the operation is needed.

Comment: Ah! so it is used in the SDK, then! But, what happens if none is provided? What does the SDK generate for a method to call the endpoint?

Comment: Some tools will make one up -- maybe based on the path and HTTP method.  Our SDK generator actually throws an error -- it requires an operationId to be specified -- primarily to avoid really ugly method names.